# Best way to extract/format data in JSON format using Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to do some data analysis on bulk patent data (data is usually found here but is currently down - https://ped.uspto.gov/peds/).

Here is the first entry in the JSON file:

```
{
  "PatentBulkData":[
    {
      "patentCaseMetadata":{
        "applicationNumberText":{
          "value":"15733015",
          "electronicText":"15733015"
        },
        "filingDate":"2020-01-01",
        "applicationTypeCategory":"Utility",
        "partyBag":{
          "applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag":[
            {
              "applicant":[
                {
                  "contactOrPublicationContact":[
                    {
                      "name":{
                        "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                          {
                            "personStructuredName":{
                              "firstName":"Birol",
                              "middleName":"",
                              "lastName":"Cimen"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      "cityName":"Hengelo",
                      "geographicRegionName":{
                        "value":"",
                        "geographicRegionCategory":"STATE"
                      },
                      "countryCode":"NL"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "partyIdentifierOrContact":[
                {
                  "name":{
                    "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                      {
                        "personStructuredName":{
                          "lastName":"Oppedahl Patent Law Firm LLC (Mink)"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "postalAddressBag":{
                    "postalAddress":[
                      {
                        "postalStructuredAddress":{
                          "addressLineText":[
                            {
                              "value":"P O Box 351240"
                            }
                          ],
                          "cityName":"Westminster",
                          "geographicRegionName":[
                            {
                              "value":"CO"
                            }
                          ],
                          "countryCode":"US",
                          "postalCode":"80035"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "value":"133517"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "groupArtUnitNumber":{
          "value":"3771",
          "electronicText":"3771"
        },
        "applicationConfirmationNumber":"7897",
        "applicantFileReference":"FP01.P035 SST02US",
        "priorityClaimBag":{
          "priorityClaim":[
            {
              "ipOfficeName":"NETHERLANDS",
              "applicationNumber":{
                "applicationNumberText":"2019179"
              },
              "filingDate":"2017-07-05",
              "sequenceNumber":"1"
            }
          ]
        },
        "patentClassificationBag":{
          "cpcClassificationBagOrIPCClassificationOrECLAClassificationBag":[
            {
              "ipOfficeCode":"US",
              "mainNationalClassification":{
                "nationalClass":"606",
                "nationalSubclass":"133000"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "businessEntityStatusCategory":"SMALL",
        "firstInventorToFileIndicator":"true",
        "inventionTitle":{
          "content":[
            "Hair removal device for removing body hair on a body surface"
          ]
        },
        "applicationStatusCategory":"Application Dispatched from Preexam, Not Yet Docketed",
        "applicationStatusDate":"2020-05-08",
        "officialFileLocationCategory":"ELECTRONIC",
        "patentPublicationIdentification":{
          "publicationNumber":"US20200170371A1",
          "publicationDate":"2020-06-04"
        },
        "relatedDocumentData":{
          "parentDocumentDataOrChildDocumentData":[
            {
              "descriptionText":"This application is National Stage Entry of",
              "applicationNumberText":"PCT/NL2018/050434",
              "filingDate":"2018-07-04",
              "parentDocumentStatusCode":"Published",
              "patentNumber":""
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "prosecutionHistoryDataBag":{
        "prosecutionHistoryData":[
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-06-05",
            "eventCode":"PG-ISSUE",
            "eventDescriptionText":"PG-Pub Issue Notification"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-05-11",
            "eventCode":"M903",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Notice of DO/EO Acceptance Mailed"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-05-11",
            "eventCode":"FLRCPT.U",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Filing Receipt - Updated"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-05-11",
            "eventCode":"MPEN",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Mail Pre-Exam Notice"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-02-26",
            "eventCode":"EML_NTR",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Email Notification"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-02-26",
            "eventCode":"EML_NTR",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Email Notification"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-02-26",
            "eventCode":"CCRDY",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Application ready for PDX access by participating foreign offices"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-01-05",
            "eventCode":"371COMP",
            "eventDescriptionText":"371 Completion Date"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-02-25",
            "eventCode":"PGPC",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Sent to Classification Contractor"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-02-25",
            "eventCode":"FTFS",
            "eventDescriptionText":"FITF set to YES - revise initial setting"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-01-02",
            "eventCode":"PTA.RFE",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Patent Term Adjustment - Ready for Examination"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-02-26",
            "eventCode":"FLRCPT.O",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Filing Receipt"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-02-26",
            "eventCode":"M903",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Notice of DO/EO Acceptance Mailed"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2019-12-31",
            "eventCode":"SREXR141",
            "eventDescriptionText":"PTO/SB/69-Authorize EPO Access to Search Results"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2019-12-31",
            "eventCode":"APPERMS",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Applicants have given acceptable permission for participating foreign "
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2020-02-25",
            "eventCode":"SMAL",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Applicant Has Filed a Verified Statement of Small Entity Status in Compliance with 37 CFR 1.27"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2019-12-31",
            "eventCode":"L194",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Cleared by OIPE CSR"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2019-12-31",
            "eventCode":"WIDS",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Information Disclosure Statement (IDS) Filed"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2019-12-31",
            "eventCode":"WIDS",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Information Disclosure Statement (IDS) Filed"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2019-12-31",
            "eventCode":"BIG.",
            "eventDescriptionText":"ENTITY STATUS SET TO UNDISCOUNTED (INITIAL DEFAULT SETTING OR STATUS CHANGE)"
          },
          {
            "eventDate":"2019-12-31",
            "eventCode":"IEXX",
            "eventDescriptionText":"Initial Exam Team nn"
          }
        ]
      },
      "st96Version":"V3_1",
      "ipoVersion":"US_V8_0"
    },
```

I import the json data as a dictionary.  However, what is the best way to obtain the information I would like to retrieve.  Should I use json.normalize to flatten it and convert to a Dataframe?

I would like to specifically retrieve information in the "prosecutionHistoryData".  For example, with other patent applications, this would provide specific information regarding how many office actions have been issued.

Eventually I would like to cross-reference this office action data by Patent Examiner (which would be found in the "applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag" when assigned to an Examiner).

Are there any good resources that explain how to clean json data such I can get break this information into separate columns?

Thank you for the information!  Here is an example with an Examiner:

```
   {
         "patentCaseMetadata":{
            "applicationNumberText":{
               "value":"16732312",
               "electronicText":"16732312"
            },
            "filingDate":"2020-01-01",
            "applicationTypeCategory":"Utility",
            "partyBag":{
               "applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag":[
                  {
                     "primaryExaminerOrAssistantExaminerOrAuthorizedOfficer":[
                        {
                           "name":{
                              "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                 {
                                    "personFullName":"ORGAD, EDAN"
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "applicant":[
                        {
                           "contactOrPublicationContact":[
                              {
                                 "name":{
                                    "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                       {
                                          "organizationStandardName":{
                                             "content":[
                                                "Communication Systems LLC"
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 },
                                 "cityName":"Santa Fe",
                                 "geographicRegionName":{
                                    "value":"NM",
                                    "geographicRegionCategory":"STATE"
                                 },
                                 "countryCode":""
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "groupArtUnitNumber":{
               "value":"2414",
               "electronicText":"2414"
            },
            "applicationConfirmationNumber":"8996",
            "applicantFileReference":"CS1003US03",
            "patentClassificationBag":{
               "cpcClassificationBagOrIPCClassificationOrECLAClassificationBag":[
                  {
                     "ipOfficeCode":"US",
                     "mainNationalClassification":{
                        "nationalClass":"370",
                        "nationalSubclass":"329000"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            },
            "businessEntityStatusCategory":"SMALL",
            "firstInventorToFileIndicator":"true",
            "inventionTitle":{
               "content":[
                  "APPARATUSES, METHODS, AND COMPUTER-READABLE MEDIUM FOR COMMUNICATION IN A WIRELESS LOCAL AREA NETWORK"
               ]
            },
            "applicationStatusCategory":"Docketed New Case - Ready for Examination",
            "applicationStatusDate":"2020-02-07",
            "officialFileLocationCategory":"ELECTRONIC",
            "patentPublicationIdentification":{
               "publicationNumber":"US20200154403A1",
               "publicationDate":"2020-05-14"
            }
         },
         "prosecutionHistoryDataBag":{
            "prosecutionHistoryData":[
               {
                  "eventDate":"2020-05-19",
                  "eventCode":"PG-ISSUE",
                  "eventDescriptionText":"PG-Pub Issue Notification"
               }
            ]
         },
         "assignmentDataBag":{
            "assignmentData":[
               {
                  "reelNumber":"52436",
                  "frameNumber":"295",
                  "documentReceivedDate":"2020-04-20",
                  "recordedDate":"2020-04-20",
                  "mailDate":"2020-04-21",
                  "pageTotalQuantity":3,
                  "conveyanceText":"ASSIGNMENT OF ASSIGNORS INTEREST (SEE DOCUMENT FOR DETAILS).",
                  "assignorBag":{
                     "assignor":[
                        {
                           "executionDate":"2016-07-14",
                           "contactOrPublicationContact":[
                              {
                                 "name":{
                                    "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                       {
                                          "value":"ATEFI, ALI"
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  "assigneeBag":{
                     "assignee":[
                        {
                           "contactOrPublicationContact":[
                              {
                                 "name":{
                                    "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                       {
                                          "value":"COMMUNICATION SYSTEMS LLC"
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 },
                                 "postalAddressBag":{
                                    "postalAddress":[
                                       {
                                          "postalAddressText":[
                                             {
                                                "sequenceNumber":"1",
                                                "value":"530-B HARKLE ROAD"
                                             },
                                             {
                                                "sequenceNumber":"2",
                                                "value":"STE. 100"
                                             },
                                             {
                                                "sequenceNumber":"3",
                                                "value":"SANTA FE NEW MEXICO 87505"
                                             }
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  "correspondenceAddress":{
                     "partyIdentifierOrContact":[
                        {
                           "name":{
                              "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                 {
                                    "value":"ALI ATEFI"
                                 }
                              ]
                           },
                           "postalAddressBag":{
                              "postalAddress":[
                                 {
                                    "postalAddressText":[
                                       {
                                          "sequenceNumber":"1",
                                          "value":"530-B HARKLE ROAD"
                                       },
                                       {
                                          "sequenceNumber":"2",
                                          "value":"STE. 100"
                                       },
                                       {
                                          "sequenceNumber":"3",
                                          "value":"SANTA FE, NM 87505"
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  "sequenceNumber":"1"
               }
            ],
            "assignmentTotalQuantity":1
         },
         "st96Version":"V3_1",
         "ipoVersion":"US_V8_0"
      },
```

My parse will not go past the applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag. Here is my example parse for trying to obtain the Examiner name, which returns an empty dataframe:

```
jsonpath_expression = parse('PatentBulkData[*].patentCaseMetadata.partyBag.applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag.primaryExaminerOrAssistantExaminerOrAuthorizedOfficer.name.personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName.personFullName[*]')
```

If I end at the applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag, I return a dataframe with proper information - just with brackets and all the other JSON notation.  Am I missing the key structure?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

For parsing more or less complex JSON documents you might wanna take a look at the `JSONPath` "query language".

There's a nice Python implementation in [`jsonpath-rw`](https://github.com/kennknowles/python-jsonpath-rw). Since the data you need is nested like this

```
{
  "PatentBulkData": [
    {
      "prosecutionHistoryDataBag": {
        "prosecutionHistoryData": [
          {
            "eventDate": "2020-06-05",
            "eventCode": "PG-ISSUE",
            "eventDescriptionText": "PG-Pub Issue Notification"
          },
```

the JSONPath would be

> Under key `PatentBulkData`, get the every element of the array, then the key `prosecutionHistoryDataBag`, then the key `prosecutionHistoryData`, and finally all array elements under that.

Or

```
PatentBulkData[*].prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData[*]
```

This is what you'd do in Python

```py
import json

from jsonpath_rw import jsonpath, parse
import pandas as pd

# Parse the string containing the whole JSON document
data = json.loads(<YOUR_JSON_STRING>)

jsonpath_expr = parse('PatentBulkData[*].prosecutionHistoryDataBag.prosecutionHistoryData[*]')

# Extract the raw value from each matching element,
# i.e. every element of the JSON array
matches = [match.value for match in jsonpath_expr.find(data)]

# Create dataframe from the list of dictionaries
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(matches)
```

Result:

```
| eventDate   | eventCode   | eventDescriptionText              |
|-------------|:------------|:----------------------------------|
| 2020-06-05  | PG-ISSUE    | PG-Pub Issue Notification         |
| 2020-05-11  | M903        | Notice of DO/EO Acceptance Mailed |
| 2020-05-11  | FLRCPT.U    | Filing Receipt - Updated          |
| 2020-05-11  | MPEN        | Mail Pre-Exam Notice              |
| 2020-02-26  | EML_NTR     | Email Notification                |
```

### EDIT

For the examiner query, you need to look out for nested arrays. Every time you get to an array in the tree, you need to either get one (`[0]`, `[1]`, etc.) or all the elements in the array (`[*]`):

```py
examiner_expr = parse(
    "PatentBulkData[*].patentCaseMetadata.partyBag"
    ".applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag[*]"
    ".primaryExaminerOrAssistantExaminerOrAuthorizedOfficer[*]"
    ".name.personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName[*]"
    ".personFullName"
)
[match.value for match in examiner_expr.find(data)]                                                                                                  
# ['ORGAD, EDAN']
```