# Best method to import Nested JSON data into Dataframes or Dictionary?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am wondering if anyone would have a suggestion on how to import nested JSON data in as a Dataframe or dictionary?  The data in question is normally available here - https://ped.uspto.gov/peds/.

Here is an example of the format of the data:

```
{
   "PatentBulkData":[ 
      {
         "patentCaseMetadata":{
            "applicationNumberText":{
               "value":"16732342",
               "electronicText":"16732342"
            },
            "filingDate":"2020-01-01",
            "applicationTypeCategory":"Utility",
            "partyBag":{
               "applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag":[
                  {
                     "primaryExaminerOrAssistantExaminerOrAuthorizedOfficer":[
                        {
                           "name":{
                              "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                 {
                                    "personFullName":"VO, PETER DUNG BA"
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "applicant":[
                        {
                           "contactOrPublicationContact":[
                              {
                                 "name":{
                                    "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                       {
                                          "organizationStandardName":{
                                             "content":[
                                                "CYNTEC CO., LTD."
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 },
                                 "cityName":"Hsinchu",
                                 "geographicRegionName":{
                                    "value":"",
                                    "geographicRegionCategory":"STATE"
                                 },
                                 "countryCode":"TW"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "groupArtUnitNumber":{
               "value":"3729",
               "electronicText":"3729"
            },
            "applicationConfirmationNumber":"1040",
            "applicantFileReference":"6101.179US",
            "patentClassificationBag":{
               "cpcClassificationBagOrIPCClassificationOrECLAClassificationBag":[
                  {
                     "ipOfficeCode":"US",
                     "mainNationalClassification":{
                        "nationalClass":"029",
                        "nationalSubclass":"602100"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            },
            "businessEntityStatusCategory":"UNDISCOUNTED",
            "firstInventorToFileIndicator":"true",
            "inventionTitle":{
               "content":[
                  "INDUCTOR WITH AN ELECTRODE STRUCTURE"
               ]
            },
            "applicationStatusCategory":"Docketed New Case - Ready for Examination",
            "applicationStatusDate":"2020-04-27",
            "officialFileLocationCategory":"ELECTRONIC",
            "patentPublicationIdentification":{
               "publicationNumber":"US20200135386A1",
               "publicationDate":"2020-04-30"
            }
         },
         "assignmentDataBag":{
            "assignmentData":[
               {
                  "reelNumber":"51406",
                  "frameNumber":"55",
                  "documentReceivedDate":"2020-01-03",
                  "recordedDate":"2020-01-03",
                  "mailDate":"2020-01-06",
                  "pageTotalQuantity":3,
                  "conveyanceText":"ASSIGNMENT OF ASSIGNORS INTEREST (SEE DOCUMENT FOR DETAILS).",
                  "assignorBag":{
                     "assignor":[
                        {
                           "executionDate":"2020-01-02",
                           "contactOrPublicationContact":[
                              {
                                 "name":{
                                    "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                       {
                                          "value":"LEE, CHI-HSUN"
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "executionDate":"2020-01-02",
                           "contactOrPublicationContact":[
                              {
                                 "name":{
                                    "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                       {
                                          "value":"HSIEH, HSIEH-SHEN"
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "executionDate":"2020-01-02",
                           "contactOrPublicationContact":[
                              {
                                 "name":{
                                    "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                       {
                                          "value":"CHEN, SEN-HUEI"
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  "assigneeBag":{
                     "assignee":[
                        {
                           "contactOrPublicationContact":[
                              {
                                 "name":{
                                    "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                       {
                                          "value":"CYNTEC CO., LTD."
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 },
                                 "postalAddressBag":{
                                    "postalAddress":[
                                       {
                                          "postalAddressText":[
                                             {
                                                "sequenceNumber":"1",
                                                "value":"NO. 2, RESEARCH & DEVELOPMENT 2ND RD."
                                             },
                                             {
                                                "sequenceNumber":"2",
                                                "value":"SCIENCE PARK"
                                             },
                                             {
                                                "sequenceNumber":"3",
                                                "value":"HSINCHU TAIWAN"
                                             }
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  "correspondenceAddress":{
                     "partyIdentifierOrContact":[
                        {
                           "name":{
                              "personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName":[
                                 {
                                    "value":"LITRON INTERNATIONAL PATENT & TRADEMARK OFFICE"
                                 }
                              ]
                           },
                           "postalAddressBag":{
                              "postalAddress":[
                                 {
                                    "postalAddressText":[
                                       {
                                          "sequenceNumber":"1",
                                          "value":"11F.-2, NO.248, SEC. 3, NANJING E. RD."
                                       },
                                       {
                                          "sequenceNumber":"2",
                                          "value":"TAIPEI CITY,  TAIWAN"
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  "sequenceNumber":"1"
               }
            ],
            "assignmentTotalQuantity":1
         },
         "st96Version":"V3_1",
         "ipoVersion":"US_V8_0"
      },
```

I bring in the data with the following:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('/content/drive/My Drive/2020.json') as json_file:
  data = json.load(json_file)
```

While this does create a dictionary, it is keyed on 'PatentBulkData'.  Thus, the remaining portion of the data is a list.  In other words, when I run

```
print(type(data['PatentBulkData']))
```

The type is a 'list'.

Ideally, I would like to go down one more level in order to create a dictionary based on the application number text, examiner name, and prosecution history bag (an example with prosecution history bag can be found here - [Best way to extract/format data in JSON format using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62844742/best-way-to-extract-format-data-in-json-format-using-python)).

The purpose of this is to get the data into a format such that I can conduct analytics based on examiner, applicant, etc.

I believe the data is also available in XML format - would XML be easier?

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: XML would probably be harder IMO. What do you mean exactly by "create a dictionary based on the application number text, examiner name, and prosecution history bag"? What would be the keys and what would be the values?

Comment: Thank you for the question, @nog642 .  To clarify, using the above data as an example, the application_value is 16732342, "groupArtUnitNumber" "value":"3729", and "primaryExaminerOrAssistantExaminerOrAuthorizedOfficer":"personFullName":"VO, PETER DUNG BA".  The values and the full name would represent the values.

Comment: Your JSON in the question is incomplete. How many items are in `data['PatentBulkData']`? Is it just one, or more than one? And I still don't understand what format you want to have the data to be in, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you're looking for is json_normalize. The Pandas documentation for it is pretty good- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

So for example, you would want to do something like:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

with open('/content/drive/My Drive/2020.json') as json_file:
  data = json.load(json_file)

df = json_normalize(data, max_level=1)
```